# collecting data from a form using asp.net and inserting it into an sql view made up of multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, forms, insert, view

I am trying to collect data from a form using asp.net and insert it into a sql view that is made up of multiple tables. however an error keeps being displayed saying 'v_orderdetails  is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.' Can anybody help, below is my code:

```
public partial class _Order : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string myConnectionString;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }

    protected void Orderbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
        myConnectionString = "server=CSSQL; database=Oh31_PE; Trusted_Connection = true";
        myConn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;

        string querystring1;
        querystring1 = "insert into v_orderdetails (dbo.t_order.OrderDate, dbo.t_product.Material, dbo.t_product.Description, dbo.t_orderdetails.Quantity) values ( '";
        querystring1 += od.Text + "','" + opname.Text + "','" + tom.Text + "','" + tod.Text + "','" + qq.Text + "')";

        SqlCommand dbcommand1 = new SqlCommand();
        dbcommand1.CommandText = querystring1;
        dbcommand1.Connection = myConn;
        myConn.Open();
        dbcommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConn.Close();

        {
            Response.Redirect("Order.aspx");
        }



    } // end Orderbtn_Click
}
```

Comment: Could you post the sql for the view v_orderdetails? That might hold the clue about why the view is not updateable.

Comment: SELECT        dbo.t_order.OrderNo, dbo.t_order.OrderDate, dbo.t_product.Material, dbo.t_product.Description, dbo.t_orderdetails.Quantity
FROM            dbo.t_order INNER JOIN
                         dbo.t_orderdetails ON dbo.t_order.OrderNo = dbo.t_orderdetails.OrderNo INNER JOIN
                         dbo.t_product ON dbo.t_orderdetails.ProductID = dbo.t_product.ProductID

Comment: I think the problem is that t_order and t_orderdetails have a one-to-many relationship. Inserting to a view directly is tricky because they have lots of restrictions on doing so. How about either a) running 2 separate inserts (one on t_order and one on t_orderdetails), or b) creating a stored procedure in the database that does the 2 inserts and then running one execute of that stored procedure in your ASP.NET code?